# query select having duplicate data between daterange

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table

```
id  | id_employee    |  start_date  | enddate
--------------------------------------------- 
1   |    A           |   01/04/2018 | 05/04/2018
2   |    B           |   03/04/2018 | 08/04/2018 
3   |    A           |   02/04/2018 | 05/04/2018
4   |    C           |   04/04/2018 | 06/04/2018
5   |    B           |   05/04/2018 | 08/04/2018
```

I want to select based from date range (from start_date to end_date) where id_employee have duplicate data (clash on daterange)

what query that i can use

Comment: With that sample table data, what is the expected result?

Comment: that is sample data, id= 1,2 and id= 2,5 that is clash of daterange, i want select data where clash on date range

Comment: Add expected output and explanation for better answer

Comment: output that i want, Id_employee A and B, because that clash on date range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT `id`, `id_employee`
FROM Table1
WHERE id_employee IN ( 
SELECT T1.id_employee
FROM `Table1` T1 
INNER JOIN
`Table1` T2
ON T1.id_employee=T2.id_employee
AND T1.id <> T2.id
AND DATE(T1.start_date)<=DATE(T2.enddate)
AND DATE(T1.enddate)>= DATE(T2.start_date)
GROUP BY T1.id_employee 
HAVING COUNT(T1.id_employee) > 1
)
ORDER BY id_employee
```

**Output**

```
id  id_employee
1   A
3   A
2   B
5   B
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1d9c9/32

Comment: Welcome!! @YanuarIhsan

Comment: sorry one more question, how if i want show result with "ID" column

Comment: For A and B which ID you want the max or min Id between those

Comment: Edited my answer @YanuarIhsan

Comment: sorry, if want to show the date on which the date of the data clash, so, result total is 8, @JayShankarGupta

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169651/discussion-between-yanuar-ihsan-and-jay-shankar-gupta).

Answer (score 0):

```
select aa.id
from `table` aa
where exists (select * from `table` bb
where bb.id <> aa.id and (bb.start_date between aa.start_date and aa.enddate
or bb.enddate between aa.start_date and aa.enddate or
aa.start_date between bb.start_date and bb.enddate
or aa.enddate between bb.start_date and bb.enddate))
```

This one checks for overlapping dates and different id. I think should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Are your date fields using datetime datatype?

Comment: result is all of id_employee, that is still wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

Your table shows 3 id_employee viz. A, B and C. Your question is not clear assuming you want a query based on date range find below :

```
SELECT id_employee FROM schema.table where start_date>='2018-04-01' and end_date<='2018-04-08' group by id_employee;
```

Comment: not from specific range (start_date and end_date), that is sample data

Comment: You may use while loop in  your program instead looking for desired results from query.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest method is:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.id_employee = t.id_employee and
                    t2.id <> t.id and
                    t2.start_date < t.end_date and
                    t2.end_date > t.start_date
             );
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/557a8d/2) is a SQL Fiddle.

You can add a date range just by adding the range to the outer query:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.id_employee = t.id_employee and
                    t2.id <> t.id and
                    t2.start_date < t.end_date and
                    t2.end_date > t.start_date
             ) and
     t.start_date <= ? and
     t.end_date >= ?;
```